# Limit checkbox to 2, but moving the select instead of blocking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

I would like to allow the client to select only 2 checkbox form a group of 4, but if they select the third one the select from one of the 2 already select will move to this third.

There is an example on this website (it most be in mobile screen size)
https://www.office-coffee.co.uk/coffee-machines-for-business/comparison/

I have this code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theCheckboxes = $(".pricing-levels-2 input[type='checkbox']");
  theCheckboxes.click(function() {
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 2)
      $(this).removeAttr("checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-2">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like?</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldnt find the checkboxes on the mentioned site..

Comment: Which one should move to the next one? First one or the second one?

Comment: You must to shrink the screen until do to mobile mode and click in compare "COMPARE OTHERS"... sorry i forgot to mention that.

Comment: Check my answer below..

Comment: The first one selected move to the third and it continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM traversal method to target a checkbox to set its `checked` property using `.prop(propertyName, value)`. Here in example I have manipulate the first checkbox property

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theCheckboxes = $(".pricing-levels-2 input[type='checkbox']");
  theCheckboxes.change(function() {
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 2) {
      theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").not(this).eq(0).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-2">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like?</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Very close, but sorry again I think I was not very clear. When click on the third one the first move to the third, but then the second one "become" the first, so when the client click on the forth one, the second one will move to the forth one. Basically the same way it is in this coffee site.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first one you can use `theCheckboxes.filter(":checked:first").removeAttr("checked");`

**For example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theCheckboxes = $(".pricing-levels-2 input[type='checkbox']");
  theCheckboxes.click(function() {
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 2)
      theCheckboxes.filter(":checked:first").removeAttr("checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-2">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like?</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Very close, but sorry again I think I was not very clear. When click on the third one the first move to the third, but then the second one "become" the first, so when the client click on the forth one, the second one will move to the forth one. Basically the same way it is in this coffee site